# Output If Backwards String Is True or False

Tags: java

The program I'm making needs to output true or false when using method backwards(), indicating if the string is backwards or not.. But it keeps displaying false when it's supposed to be true...

```
public class StringImproved
{
   private String word;

public StringImproved(String word)
{
  this.word = word; 
}
public String getWord()
{
  return(this.word); 
}
public void setWord(String word)
{
  this.word = word; 
}
public int size()
 {
  return(this.word.length()); 
 }
 public boolean backwards(String word)
{
   String backwards = "";
   for(int i = getWord().length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
     backwards += getWord().charAt(i);
    }
   if(backwards == word)
   {
   return true; 
   }
   else return false;
    }
}


public class test
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
 {
 StringImproved si=new StringImproved("lag");
 System.out.println(si.backwards("gal")); 

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
if(backwards == word)
```

you need to use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) instead of `==`:

```
if(backwards.equals(word))
```

This is because `==` just checks whether the `backwards` and `word` variables point to the same object, whereas `equals` checks whether the objects pointed to by the two variables have the same contents.